# openCV matrix math behavior change going from python to c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

The big picture is that I am attempting to do a alpha-blend using a gradation contained in a mask. I have a handful of canvas Mat objects and associated alpha_mask Mat objects.
I alpha-blend the canvas on to the final using the associated alpha_mask, which is the displayed output.

canvas[i] is datatype 16  8-bit unsigned 3 layer
final is datatype 16  8-bit unsigned 3 layer
alpha_mask[i] is datatype 5  floating point 1 layer

My python code is working:

```py
final = cv.convertScaleAbs(canvas[i] * alpha_mask[i] + final * (1-alpha_mask[i]))
```

When I try the same with C++ I get a run-time matrix multiplication error (I think):

```c++
convertScaleAbs(canvas[i] * alpha_mask[i] + final * (1.0-alpha_mask[i]), final, 1,0);
```

Here is the error message:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.1.2) /usr/local/src/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.dispatch.cpp:337: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == B.type() in function 'gemm'

What should I do?

Comment: Unrelated to problem: Don't use `final` as identifier in C++. It is a keyword since C++11. While it isn't a reserved identifier outside of the specific syntax where the `final` keyword applies, using it in other context will be confusing. See for example the syntax highlighting in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opencv error multiplying 2 Mat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049811/opencv-error-multiplying-2-mats)